# user_can() not working for comment authors

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I'm trying to do some capability checks on comment authors using the user_can() function, but for some reason it isn't working at all.

I have a custom capability setup with the Role Manager plugin called "read_citizen".

My check looks like this:

```
if(user_can($commentAuthor->user_id, 'read_citizen') {
   //do stuff here
}
```

I have confirmed that the $commentAuthor object is set correctly.

Ideas?

Comment: "Not working" is not saying much. What does not work? What did you expect? What did actually happen? Is there an error in the error log?

Comment: It is supposed to return TRUE if the user has the capability. In this case, nothing is returned.

Comment: What if you use a non-custom cap? Does the conditional return `true`? Also: by "nothing is returned", do you mean that the conditional returns `null`, or that it returns `false`?

Comment: try using `current_user_can('read_citizen')` instead

Comment: In PHP the value `nothing` does not exist. What does the function **exactly** return? `FALSE` or `NULL` or even something else?

Comment: @Bainternet would I then couple that with something like set_current_user() ?

Comment: @Chip - does not work even with a non custom. I tried "read".

Comment: @Bainternet - Here's what I've been trying: `global $current_user; wp_set_current_user($commentAuthor->user_ID); get_currentuserinfo();` The problem is that $current_user is NULL then. Ideas? Oh, FYI, this is inside a custom comments callback.

Comment: Why are you using `current_user_can()` instead of `user_can()`? Which one is appropriate? Do you need to find out if the *comment author* has a given capability, or if the *current site visitor* has a given capability?

Comment: @Chip - I first tried it with user_can() because I'm checking if the comment user has a capability. I then tried current_user_can() to do the same thing by also using wp_set_current_user()

Comment: Why confound things by altering the current user? I would recommend sticking with `user_can( $commentAuthor->user_id, 'cap' )`

Comment: @chip - that was my thought too. I simply did it because it wasn't working. So I tried it. I actually just found the solution and will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. It was just an oversight on my part.

I was using the wrong variable name for the USER ID. In the $wpdb comment object, the user ID is stored as `user_id`, but in the USER object, the ID is stored just as `ID`.

So, by using `if ( user_can($commentAuthor->ID, 'read_citizen') )`, it all works.